# VB.NET Copy Local Directory Contents to Another Directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, syntax, copy

I have a straight-forward task I'm attempting to accomplish.  I have the mechanics down, and need to hammer out the details but I'm stumbling across one small point. :)

This script is supposed to take the files in the local C:\Temp\ directory, and copy them to a selected user's shared directory on the file server.

```
Protected Sub btnCopy_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCopy.Click
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Temp\", "\\MAVERICK\VOL1\Users\" & ddlName.SelectedValue & "\DESKTOP\RECORDINGS\", True)
End Sub
```

This script does indeed work (and I'm aware I need to create exception handling) but it only copies what contents are on the server's directory of C:\Temp\ rather than the local source directory.

I'm using VB.NET/ASP.NET to achieve this.

How am I able to direct my function to use the local user's directory rather than the remote server?

Comment: There may be other methods to making this work.  I've spent several hours piecing together various examples, and this was the only one that seemed to have worked for my environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is an ASP.Net application and the code is executing on a web page's button click, then what you are trying to do, copy files from the machine of the user that pressed the button to some other location, is not possible.

If this were possible, nefarious people could setup web sites to steal the files from your machine with the simple click of a button.

There are a couple possible solutions:

1) Deploy an application to the user's machine that performs this task (you could use .Net click once applications to reduce the distribution and update overhead).

2) Create a file upload mechanism within the web application using either straight HTML or a component such as a silverlight application where the users can select the files to be moved.

Comment: Good point, @competent_tech . I hadn't thought of the negative impact of such a function. I appreciate the suggestions as well.

Comment: Just an update - I created a ClickOnce VB App and was able to successfully deploy this solution.  Thank you for the help, @Competent_Tech!